# Why does backup file size become enormous when Agent schedule is changed?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I have a database that is currently backed up every two hours.  This is a secondary backup, done in addition to the hosting provider's backup strategy.  I created a procedure (stored within `master`) to perform the following actions on a scheduled basis in SQL Agent:

1. If the backup file doesn't exist create it and perform a full (copy only) backup
2. If the backup file does exist, perform a transaction log backup

The code creates a backup file with a weekly date stamp (e.g. `2017_Week37_myDbName.bak`), then drops and re-creates a new file each week.

The code is currently scheduled to run every two hours, which for my level of understanding meant I would have a maximum of two hours data loss in the event of failure.  The initial backup file created in step 1 is 230MB, which obviously increases every two hours as the transaction log backup is added.  Each week, the file reaches a size of around 7GB, before being deleted by the procedure.

I then changed the schedule to run every 15 minutes, but noticed that the backup file went **over 230GB** - a gigantic increase.  There may be a bug (which I cannot figure), but I'm wondering why this would happen?  I thought that the transaction log backup would only contain the transactions backed up since the last backup, so regardless of the frequency, the backup file would always be a similar size before it was deleted.  I should clarify that at no point was the database used any more frequently than normal.  Basically, I am trying to create differential-style backups after the initial full backup.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[BackupMyDB]

    @myDbName nvarchar(50)

AS

    DECLARE @year nvarchar(4) = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS nvarchar);
    DECLARE @weekNumber nvarchar(2) = CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(wk, getdate())), 2) as nvarchar);
    DECLARE @backupFileName nvarchar(max) = @year + '_Week' + @weeknumber + '_' + @mydbname; -- '2013_Week37_myDbName'
    DECLARE @backupPhysicalPath nvarchar(100) = N'C:\SqlScheduledBackups\';
    DECLARE @fullPath nvarchar(150) = @backupphysicalpath + @backupFileName;
    DECLARE @backupName nvarchar(200);

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.backup_devices WHERE (name=@backupFileName))
        BEGIN

            -- create backup device and perform full backup
            EXEC master.dbo.sp_addumpdevice  @devtype=N'disk', @logicalname=@backupFileName, @physicalname=@fullpath;
            SET @backupname = @myDbName + '-Full Database Backup';
            BACKUP DATABASE @mydbname TO  @backupFileName WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, RETAINDAYS=45, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME=@backupname, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10;

            -- delete the previous backup file
            DECLARE @previousBackupName nvarchar(200);
            SELECT
                  TOP 1 @previousBackupName = o.name
            FROM
                sys.backup_devices o
            WHERE
                (o.name <> @backupfilename) AND
                (o.name LIKE @year + '_Week_%_' + @mydbname)
            ORDER BY
                o.name ASC;

            IF @previousBackupName IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropdevice @logicalname = @previousBackupName, @delfile='delfile';
                END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @backupname = @myDbName + '-Transaction Log Backup';
            BACKUP LOG @mydbname TO  @backupFileName WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME=@backupname, SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS=10;
        END
GO
```

Comment: EvilDr, If you need a better backup solution then I personally recommend using [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-backup.html), Then enable every 1mins log backup, everyday 1 full backup. The reason why it grows to 230Gb is it might be a huge transaction or the previous backups have not happened.

Comment: How often does the provider issue `BACKUP LOG` commands.  Your log backups are `COPY_ONLY`, so each run of your process will back up everything in the log since the last NON-COPY_ONLY backup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't indicate how often your provider issues `BACKUP LOG` commands (which I assume are not `COPY_ONLY`), but here is my guess at to what is happening.

Let's assume a 'regular' transaction log backup has occurred at 8am which truncates the log.  Also, let's assume that 1gb of transaction log is being created every 15 minutes.

- 8:00am - Your `BACKUP LOG COPY_ONLY` runs and doesn't really backup
  anything because the log has just been truncated by the normal log
  backup.
- 8:15am - Your `BACKUP LOG COPY_ONLY` runs and backs up up everything
  since 8:00am  (because that's when the log was last truncated). Let's say 1gb.
- 8:30am - Your `BACKUP LOG COPY_ONLY`  runs and backs up everything
  since 8:00am (because that's when the log was last truncated) - now 2gb.
- 8:45am - Your `BACKUP LOG COPY_ONLY`  runs and backs up everything
  since 8:00am (because that's when the log was last truncated) - now 3gb.
- 9:00am - Your `BACKUP LOG COPY_ONLY`  runs and backs up everything
  since 8:00am (because that's when the log was last truncated) - now 4gb

You are also 'appending' this data to your existing backup because you are using `NOINIT`.

Comment: `NOINIT` for the win... or rather loss (of disk space) in this scenario...

Comment: Fantastic explanation - thank you.  Yes indeed, `NOINIT` was the cause.

Comment: Still having some issues.  Would appreciate any attention you might be able to spare [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/185595/transaction-log-backup-overwrites-full-backup-on-same-media) please...