# Transaction Log backup overwrites full backup on same media

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, backup

I have a database that is currently backed up every two hours using a SQL Agent job. This is a secondary backup, done in addition to the hosting provider's backup strategy. I created a procedure (stored within master) to perform the following actions on a scheduled basis in SQL Agent:

1. If the backup file doesn't exist, create it and perform a full (copy only) backup
2. If the backup file does exist, perform a transaction log backup

The code creates a backup file with a weekly date stamp (e.g. 2017_Week37_myDbName.bak), then drops and re-creates a new file each week.

The code is below:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[e4_backupDB]

    @myDbName nvarchar(50)

AS

    DECLARE @year nvarchar(4) = CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS nvarchar(4));
    DECLARE @weeknumber nvarchar(2) = CAST(RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(wk, getdate())), 2) as nvarchar(2));
    DECLARE @backupFileName nvarchar(max) = @year + '_Week' + @weeknumber + '_' + @mydbname; -- '2013_Week37_myDbName'
    DECLARE @backupphysicalpath nvarchar(100) = N'C:\SqlScheduledBackups\';  
    DECLARE @fullpath nvarchar(150) = @backupphysicalpath + @backupFileName;  
    DECLARE @backupName nvarchar(200);

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.backup_devices WHERE (name=@backupFileName))
        BEGIN

            PRINT 'Creating backup device and performing full backup...';

            -- create backup device and perform full backup
            EXEC master.dbo.sp_addumpdevice  @devtype=N'disk', @logicalname=@backupFileName, @physicalname=@fullpath;
            SET @backupname = @myDbName + '-Full';
            BACKUP DATABASE @mydbname TO  @backupFileName WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, INIT, NAME=@backupname, STATS=10;

            -- delete the previous backup file
            DECLARE @previousBackupName nvarchar(200);
            SELECT
                  TOP 1 @previousBackupName = o.name
            FROM
                sys.backup_devices o
            WHERE
                (o.name <> @backupfilename) AND
                (o.name LIKE @year + '_Week_%_' + @mydbname)
            ORDER BY
                o.name ASC;

            IF @previousBackupName IS NOT NULL
                BEGIN
                    EXEC master.dbo.sp_dropdevice @logicalname = @previousBackupName, @delfile='delfile';
                END
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Performing transaction log backup...';
            SET @backupname = @myDbName + '-Transaction Log';
            BACKUP LOG @mydbname TO @backupFileName WITH COPY_ONLY, COMPRESSION, INIT,  NAME=@backupname, STATS=10;
        END
GO
```

After a few hours, if I open the backup media in SSMS and view its contents, I would expect to see:

1. A full database backup for `@myDbName`
2. The most recently-taken transaction log backup

Instead, it appears that the transaction log backup is overwriting the full backup.  When I view the media contents, I only see the transaction log.  I know that `INIT` might trigger this behaviour, but MSDN implies that if the `NAME` doesn't match, then it shouldn't get overwritten.

Why is the full backup getting replaced then please?  I am trying to achieve a full backup once-per-week, then a transaction log backup every 15 minutes.

Comment: There is no reliable way to build a log chain with COPY_ONLY log backups.  Every time your hosting provider takes a non-COPY_ONLY log backup it will break the "log chain" for your COPY_ONLY log backups.   This is because the transaction log records that occur between your last COPY_ONLY log backup and the non-COPY-ONLY log backup will be missing.

Comment: I'll second @DavidBrowne-Microsoft: Your transaction logs are going to be completely useless as is. Only you *or* your hosting provider can take transaction log backups and have them re reliable. Is there any reason you don't trust your hosting provider to do this for you?

Comment: The provider takes a VSS backup at 02:00am each day using R1Soft. However, they have been unable to clarify if the log chain is affected by this. I am waiting for an update but in the meantime am trying to put a non destructive mechanism in place

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are specifying `INIT` on both your FULL and transaction log backups.

If you want to 'append' the transaction log backups to the `FULL` backup, specify `INIT` on the FULL and `NOINIT` on the transaction log backups.

If you don't want your transaction log backups 'appended' to your FULL, I'd suggest generating a dynamic transaction log backup command 'appending' a timestamp onto the transaction log backup file name and using INIT.

Here is an 'example'

```
SET NOCOUNT ON 
declare @BackupTimeStamp varchar(25)
declare @BackupCommand varchar(max)
declare @VerifyCommand varchar(max)
declare @ServerName varchar(max) = (select @@SERVERNAME)

set @BackupTimeStamp = 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),datepart(year,sysdatetime())),4) + '_' + 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(2),datepart(month,sysdatetime())),2) + '_' + 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),datepart(day,sysdatetime())),2) + '_' + 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),datepart(hour,sysdatetime())),2) + 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),datepart(minute,sysdatetime())),2) + 
    right('00' + CONVERT(varchar(4),datepart(second,sysdatetime())),2)

set @BackupCommand = 
'
BACKUP LOG [SCOPERATIONAL] TO  
DISK = ''\\FBPISILON01\DBBackups-SC\' + @ServerName + '\Xlogs\SCOPERATIONAL_backup_' + @BackupTimeStamp + '.bax'' ' + 
'WITH FORMAT, INIT,  NAME = ''SCOPERATIONAL_BACKUPS\SCOPERATIONAL_backup_' + @BackupTimeStamp + ''''
print @BackupCommand
exec (@BackupCommand)  --should probably be sp_executesql
```

Keep in mind, that **EACH** transaction log backup will continue to be larger **UNTIL** a non-`COPY_ONLY` backup is taken.

Additionally, should you decide to create transaction log backups that are not appended to your `FULL` backups, you'll need to create some sort of pruning/purging process to delete older transaction log backups.